# How to catch array sent by PHP script as Ajax response and use further?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on an e-commerce project for practice and right now I am building product filters. So I have three files

1. catalogue.php

   - It basically shows all the products.

   product filters on left and displays products on right. When user checks a box then AJAX call is made.
2. productsfilter.js

   - It contains Javascript and AJAX calls.

     ```
     var themearray = new Array();       
     $('input[name="tcheck"]:checked').each(function(){          
     themearray.push($(this).val());     
     });
     if(themearray=='') $('.spanbrandcls').css('visibility','hidden');
     var theme_checklist = "&tcheck="+themearray;

     var main_string = theme_checklist;
     main_string = main_string.substring(1, main_string.length)
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mod/product_filter.php",
     data: main_string, 
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
         replyVal = JSON.parse(myAjax.responseText);     
         alert(replyVal);                
     }
     });
     ```
3. product_filter.php

   - It is the PHP script called by the AJAX call.

     ```
       $tcheck = $objForm->getPost('tcheck');
       if(!empty($tcheck)) {
         if(strstr($tcheck,',')) {
           $data1 = explode(',',$tcheck);
           $tarray = array();
           foreach($data1 as $t) {
           $tarray[] = "adv.attribute_deterministic_id = $t";
       }
       $WHERE[] = '('.implode(' OR ',$tarray).')';
       } else {
          $WHERE[] = '(adv.attribute_deterministic_id = '.$tcheck.')';
       }
      }
      $w = implode(' AND ',$WHERE);
      if(!empty($w)) 
      {
         $w = 'WHERE '.$w;
      }
      $results = $objCatalogue->getResults($w);
      echo json_encode($results);
     ```

So product_filter.php returns an array of `product_id`s retrieved from the database and gives it back to AJAX. Now the problem is: that array of product ids I got from AJAX call, how do I use it in catalogue.php?

As I got `{["product_id" : "1"]}` from product_filter.php, I want to use this id in catalogue.php and find the related attributes and display the product details.

How can I pass this array to my catalogue.php page so that it can use this array and call further PHP functions on it?

If the question is unclear then kindly say so, and I will try to explain it as clearly as I can. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't call PHP functions on the client. PHP is running on the server. Javascript on the client, in the browser.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I know that but how to use this array of ids to display products then? Any rough would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get data from one php and send it to a different php page then have the ajax callback process the results from that second page.

You have at  least 2 options

---

### Option 1 (the way I would do it)

In `product_filter.php`, near the top, do this

`include('catalogue.php');`

still in `product_filter.php` somewhere have your function

```
function getFilterStuff($someDataFromAjax){
    // ... do some stuff here to filter or whatever
    $productData = getCatalogueStuff($results);
    echo json_encode($productData);
    exit;
}
```

In `catalogue.php` somewhere have that function

```
function getCatalogueStuff($resultsFromFilter){
    // ... get product data here
    return $productData;
}
```

Then in your Ajax do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // add this
    url: "mod/filter_products.php",
    data: main_string,
    
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        replyVal = response;
        alert(replyVal);
    }
});
```

---

### Option 2

Nested ajax calls like this:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json", // add this
     url: "mod/filter_products.php",
     data: main_string,
     cache: false,
     success: function (filterResponse) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json", // add this
             url: "catalogue.php",
             data: filterResponse,
             cache: false,
             success: function (catalogueResponse) {
                 alert(catalogueResponse);
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Okay, I did that but still how to access this in my catalogue.php or to be more specific in the portion where I display my products?
I want to use this `{"data":[{"product_id":"1"}]}` to find and display the product on the right side of the page. Thanks!

Comment: Ah,, gimme just a moment I see.

Comment: Did you came up with anything?

Comment: What I really want to do is that catalogue.php contains filters as in SIZE, PRICE (with possible values as checkboxes) and likes on the left and products are displayed on the right. 
Now if a user clicks on Size SMALL then an AJAX call is made to PRODUCT_FILTER.php and an array of product_ids is returned which corresponds to products having small size as AJAX response.
Now I want to use this array of product_ids to find products in database and display the corresponding details of the products.

Comment: Not sure I follow, where does "catalogue.php" come in?

Comment: catalogue.php is basically a PHP page with two divs : left one for "FILTERS" and right one for "DISPLAY OF PRODUCTS". Now when user checks small size then an array of product_ids is returned via AJAX call. I am just not getting how to use this array further as in how to use this array to actually display products.